# Is the subset a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given a subset
\begin{equation} S = \{f \in C[-1,1]: f^{-1}[\{0\}]=\{0\}\} \end{equation}
and am supposed to determine if it is a subspace of $C[-1,1]$.

Now, I don't think there exists a function that is continuous on $[-1,1]$ whose inverse determined at $0$ is equal to $0$, and therefore the subset is empty, which would mean that it is not a subspace of $C[-1,1]$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The subset isn't empty. Take the constant function f(x)=0.

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Why wouldn't there exist such a function?

Comment: There is such a function, there are many. However, it is true that the set is not a subspace of the space of countinupus functions.

Comment: @Ben: The function $f(x) = 0, x \in [-1, 1]$ doesn't have an inverse at $0$.  (Or equivalently, its inverse is the whole interval.)

Comment: @Ben If $f(x)$ is the zero function then $f^{-1}(\{0\})=[-1,1]$.

Comment: Whoops that an obvious mistake

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you, could you give me an example of such a function?

Comment: $f(x) = x$ is such a function.  It is continuous on $[-1, 1]$, and the pre-image of $\{0\}$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: $f(x)=x$; $f(x)=x^3$. These two are bijective. For a non-bijective, $f(x)=x^2$, or $f(x)=x/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is not empty because it contains the identity function.

Nevertheless, the set is not a subspace because it does not contain the zero function.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that simple explanation.

Comment: @Brian Tung: Your reasoning shows this set is not even closed under addition, so your answer is useful.

Comment: Fair enough; I'll bring it back.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** There are many such $f$; however, can you come up with two functions, each of which only take on the value $0$ at $x = 0$, but whose *sum* takes on the value $0$ at multiple $x$ values?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x, g(x)=-x$, then $f+g \notin S$